# JBoss Developer Studio MAVEN project

Tags: jboss

If I create a new maven project named "getting-started" of type maven-archetype-webapp with the JBoss Developer Studio, then I get the following warning:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Build path specifies execution environment J2SE-1.5. There are no JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible with this environment.   getting-started     Build path  JRE System Library Problem
```

I installed Java SE 7 and set the system variable Java_Home to the jdk directory. Also I set by the installation wizard of JBoss DS the path to the jdk directory.

Comment: Recommendation: use Netbeans or Intellij. These IDEs both have good Maven-intergration. Both were developed after 'Maven' came along.

Answer (score 1):

Check the Java Build Path for the project:
1. In JBoss Developer Studio, right-click the project.
2. Click Properties.
3. On the left, click Java Build Path.
4. On the Libraries tab, select the current JRE System Library and click Remove.
5. Click Add Library to add a different JRE System Library (you should be able to select the Workspace default JRE).